# Should a website footer contain recent blog posts?

Tags: blog, footers

My company's website is developed in modx and the blog is hosted on hubspot.

Currently, both the website and the blog contain a simple footer that only has copyright information. Additionally, the blog site lists recent blog posts in a sidebar.

My question is should the website footer contain recent blog posts considering the blog site already lists recent posts in a sidebar? Should I remove the recent blog posts from the sidebar and put them in the footer on both the main site and the blog? Should I keep everything as it is? Or is there another option that is a best practice?

Answer (score 2):

*It depends*.

- Do you have a lot of content in the side bar?
- Is the list above/below the fold?
- And most of all: does it work now?

There isn't a general rule where to put recent/top posts. If you're providing the posts strictly for SEO purposes, then you should be [careful with footer links](http://www.linkbuildr.com/footer-links-google-penalty/).

If it's strictly for the users, you can't generally say that links in the footer are generally bad UX, e.g. see this [Nielsen article about SEO and fat footers](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/seo-and-usability/).

My suggestion:

1. Define a goal (e.g. clicks on the links)
2. Run an A/B test with both versions
3. Implement the better one

Comment: What would your personal recommendation?

Comment: I just want to add that "fat footers" are not always considered bad UX. From the Neilsen article you refered to "fat footers can greatly increase usability for people who arrive at the end of a page without finding what they want"

Comment: @Mathias I think that's what msparer was saying.

Comment: @MattObee Yes, I misread "can't" as "can" in "you can't generally say that links in the footer are generally bad UX"

Answer (score 0):

Having recent posts in footer is only good option when your blogpost more engaging. If you normally post posts that are for reference, avoid blogpost.

Showing one single latest post helps user to understand what the type of articles that your site posts on blog.

Answer (score 0):

In short No. The footer would (should) contain information that usually will not be updated including but not limited to contact info, about us, help, privacy info.